# Sampling from matrix-normal distribution

Tags: sampling

I would like to sample from a matrix-Gaussian variable (not multivariate normal). so basically, let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a random matrix distributed according to the matrix-normal law. Let it be zero mean. We can denote this distribution with,
$${vec}(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,Q_1 \otimes Q_2)$$
where $vec$ is the vectorization operator, $0$ is the $m\times n$ all zero matrix. $\dim(Q_1) = n\times n$ and $\dim(Q_2) = m\times m$.

The obvious way to sample this in general of course is to sample this vectorized object and reshaping it. But this requires to compute this Kronecker product which can certainly be burdensome.

**My problem:** I would like to sample the matrix directly using $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ without computing the Kronecker product.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the matrix normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) appears to have a clear, succinct answer. Basically, you draw a standard matrix Normal variable and conjugate it by square roots of the two covariance matrices.

Comment: See the section **Conclusion** in [this paper](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixNormal/vignettes/introduction-to-matrixnormal-package.html) for a discussion on various methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the section **Drawing values from the distribution** of the wikipage
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution

P.S.:
To obtain $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I \otimes I)$, you only need to generate $n$ independent $m$-variate normal random vectors, then stack them into an $n \times m$ matrix.